# UDP Server "Not yet connected" exception when trying to send data using write()

Tags: java, server, udp, nio

My code fails in line `cchannel_dtg.write(inBuffer)` with the exception "java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException". I've tried using the "connect" call in various variations, like shown in first piece of code below. However all of these variations resulted in an error or server not receiving the client's message. What's the cause and possible solution ??

Piece of code for UDP server set up:

```
   //UDP Server
    DatagramChannel udp_channel = DatagramChannel.open();
    udp_channel.configureBlocking(false);
    InetSocketAddress isa2 = new InetSocketAddress(9000); //9000 is a port num
    udp_channel.socket().bind(isa2);
    // Below are the options I tried of connecting the socket. All result in either : 
    //      "java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect"  OR
    //      the code compiles but Server can't "see" the UDP client and no message is read.
    //udp_channel.socket().connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.38", 9000));
    //udp_channel.socket().connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9000));
    //udp_channel.socket().connect(isa2);
    udp_channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

Piece of code that listens to the client and then sends that same message back :

```
                     inBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BUFFERSIZE);
                     outBuffer = CharBuffer.allocate(BUFFERSIZE); //Size the inBuffer to accomodate BUFFERSIZE bytes to send

                     inBuffer.clear();
                     outBuffer.clear();

                     // Receive data into inBuffer from the socket

                      cchannel_dtg.receive(inBuffer);

                      inBuffer.flip();      // make buffer available  
                      decoder.decode(inBuffer, outBuffer, false);
                      outBuffer.flip();
                      line = outBuffer.toString().trim();
                      System.out.println("UDP Client: " + line);  //Works perfect without .connect() 

                      // Echo the message back

                      inBuffer.flip();
                      bytesSent = cchannel_dtg.write(inBuffer); //Fails to write with exception: 
                                                  //  "java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException"
```

Comment: Where's the code to send the response back to the address the query came from?

Comment: `cchannel_dtg.write(inBuffer);` should take care of that, no? since i'm using the select() for this server

Comment: I don't know how to check where the message came from. A modified version works with a TCP Client with no issue.

Comment: You're not quite getting my point. You need to send the response back to the IP address and port that the query came from. Where is the code to do that? You have an unconnected datagram and you are writing data to it -- how is the implementation supposed to know where to send it? You need to stash the source address and port of the query and send the reply to that IP and port.

Comment: Thanks so much. I added : `SocketAddress client = cchannel_dtg.receive(inBuffer);
          cchannel_dtg.connect(client); `. That's where the client's address was!

Comment: Why did you repost this question at all, let alone given that you already had an answer?

Answer (score 0):

To get the clien't address, we need the lines: `SocketAddress client = cchannel_dtg.receive(inBuffer); cchannel_dtg.connect(client);`